# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication1.UserInfo]'

Tags: c#, json, wcf, serialization, asp.net-web-api

Im getting this exception. I don't understand what should i do. I have googled a lot but found nothing.

What I am doing is calling some external source API (Get call) and like to display it in my application.

**Json format**

`{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "bdcbec60-b8a7-4060-85d5-8a3370660d84",
            "first_name": "Jarin",
            "last_name": "Schmidt",
            "current_position_name": null,
            "current_organization_name": null,
            "confirmed": true,
            "photo_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/acclaim-sandbox-app/users/photos/standard/ad18cca72f6c53298dfe844a955c36e9b0bd3ace.jpg?1381944301"
        },
        {
            "id": "6cfdace6-932a-4bf8-ac5c-55a1b881e8a9",
            "first_name": "Jonathan",
            "last_name": "Miranda",
            "current_position_name": null,
            "current_organization_name": null,
            "confirmed": true,
            "photo_url": null
        },
        {
            "id": "9bd5a8a7-b002-404d-ae96-c8342329c9bc",
            "first_name": "Brent",
            "last_name": "Kastner",
            "current_position_name": null,
            "current_organization_name": null,
            "confirmed": true,
            "photo_url": null
        },
        {
            "id": "67896042-dde3-4967-8c94-624b5b6969d3",
            "first_name": "Brent",
            "last_name": "Kastner",
            "current_position_name": null,
            "current_organization_name": null,
            "confirmed": true,
            "photo_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/acclaim-sandbox-app/users/photos/standard/90f1dee38456370f0fcc3a9e41aa3ade7c7d7745.jpg?1387221013"
        },
        {
            "id": "98f7c4e0-6849-4048-a0c7-64fbb59a3da5",
            "first_name": "Christopher",
            "last_name": "Hjelmberg",
            "current_position_name": null,
            "current_organization_name": null,
            "confirmed": true,
            "photo_url": null
        },
        {
            "id": "eec79b27-3fdc-488c-b5a3-e71ebd69ec44",
            "first_name": "rajesh",
            "last_name": "arumugam",
            "current_position_name": "Software Engg",
            "current_organization_name": "GlobalEnglish",
            "confirmed": true,
            "photo_url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/acclaim-sandbox-app/users/photos/standard/ff5a28148397dd374626af5c9feae52e770774b2.JPG?1392875628"
        }
    ],
    "metadata": null
}`

**My code:**

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string baseUrl = "https://url/accessdata/userinfo.json";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic TFVBV0dkeFZlSklJZ0hjajM0M0I6");

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string var = "hai";
            // Parse the response body. Blocking!
            var UserInfo = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<UserData>>().Result;
            UserData root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(UserInfo);
            foreach (var info in employees)
                ﻿{
                   // logic to display in application
                 }
        }
```

and the **Userdata class:**

```
 public class UserInfo
{
  public  string id { get; set; }
  public string first_name { get; set; }
  public string last_name { get; set; }
  public string current_position_name { get; set; }
  public string current_organization_name { get; set; }
  public string confirmed { get; set; }
  public string photo_url { get; set; }
}
public class UserData
{
    public List<UserInfo> UserData { get; set; }
}
```

please let me know what do i need to change
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is possible that the problem is due to the presence of final `metadata` field in your JSON? Please remove it and try again.

Comment: As i said it is an external API call,Which I can able to consume

Comment: I know, but I was just suggesting you to hard-code a modified version of the JSON into the code, just for testing... it was just to determine if the problem was due to the presence of `metadata`. Anyway, please also consider what @Uriil has written in his answer: you should also add `JsonProperty("data")` attribute to your class member

Comment: I have another dought like I want to add authorization token   'client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic TFVBV0dkeFZlSklJZ0hjajM0M0I6");'                like this ?Because I am getting 401:unauthorized

Comment: @user2524095: this is another question, so please accept my previous answer if it solved *THIS* question and ask a new question for your new issue...

Comment: Ok, so let's concentrate on the unsolved issue... exactly what you have done and which is the error now?

Answer (score 0):

Response is not array of users, it's object containing `data` and `metadata`, so you should update this row:

```
   var UserInfo = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserData>().Result;
```

And this class:

```
   public class UserData
   {
       public List<UserInfo> data { get; set; }
   }
```

Or you might wanna add attribute for correct name:

```
   public class UserData
   {
       [JsonProperty("data")]
       public List<UserInfo> UserData { get; set; }
   }
```